# Including jQuery js file along with rich:dropDownMenu

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I created a drop down menu using `<rich:dropDownMenu>` and also created an image slide show using jQuery. When I import jquery .js files the drop down menu is not working.  I can't understand why the dropdown menu is not working when the .js files are included.  Otherwise it works fine if there is no image slideshow.  Either dropdownmenu or image slideshow works at same time but I need both work together.

Comment: Try to check functions names. Maybe some of your functions have the same name as jquery functions.

Comment: Seeing code or a fiddle would help....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your jquery.js is included at last and the other js files required for your dropdown menus are included before the jquery.js.

Answer (score 0):

RichFaces already ships with jQuery bundled. You don't need to include the main jQuery file yourself. If you do this and it is of a different version, then it may conflict.

You can always manually add more jQuery plugin files which RichFaces don't ship with.